# How to know wireless network driver.

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking

I am using ubuntu 12.04. How to know that my wireless card driver is ath9k or ath5k?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
```

that command will tell you your wireless and ehternet device and any driver that is loaded for them.

Also you could run:

```
lsmod
```

that command will show you all drivers loaded which are called modules actually in linux.